# Rethinking my approach to scraping dynamic content with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I am working on a project that will scrape content from various similarly designed websites which contain dynamic content. My end goal is to then aggregate all this data into one application or report of sorts. I made some progress in terms of pulling the needed data from one page but my lack of experience and knowledge in this realm has left me thinking I went down the wrong path.

https://dutchie.com/embedded-menu/revolutionary-clinics-somerville/menu

The above link is the perfect example of the type of page I will be pulling from.

In my initial attempt I was able to have the page scroll to the bottom all the while collecting data from the various elements using, plus the manual scroll.
`cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='product-card__Content']")`
This allowed me to on the fly pull all the data points I needed, minus the overarching category, which happens to be a parent element, this is something I can map manually in excel, but would prefer to be able to have it pulled alongside everything else.

This got me thinking that maybe I should have taken a top down approach, rathen then what I am seeing as a bottom up approach? But no matter how hard I try based on advice on others I could not get it working as intended where I can pull the category from the parent div due to my lack of understanding.

Based on input of others I was able to make a pivot of sorts and using the below code, I was able to get the category as well as the product name, without any need to scroll the page at all, which went against every experience I have had with this project so far - I am unclear how/why this is possible.

```
for product_group_name in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='products-grid__ProductGroupTitle']"):

    for product in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'products-grid__ProductGroup')][./div[starts-with(@class,'products-grid__ProductGroupTitle')][text()='" + product_group_name.text + "']]//div[starts-with(@class,'consumer-product-card__InViewContainer')]"):
               
        print (product_group_name.text, product.text)
```

The problem with this code, which is much quicker as it does not rely on scrolling, is that no matter how I approach it I am unable to pull the additional data points of brand and price. Obviously it is something in my approach, but outside of my knowledge level currently.

Any specific or general advice would be appreciated as I would like to scale this into something a bit more robust as my knowledge builds, I would like to be able to have this scanning multiple different URLS at set points in the day, long way away from this but I want to make sure I start on the right path if possible. Based off what I have provided, is the top down approach better in this case? Bottom up? Is this subjective?

I have noticed comments about pulling the entire source code of the page and working with that, would that be a valid approach and possibly better suited to my needs? Would it even be possible based on the dynamic nature of the page?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you could shorten your locators... target what you need.  For instance, you could probably remove everything before "text()='" + product_group_name.text".  If you get the divs you need, remember that you can run additional find methods on those webelements.  Make it relative to get at the brand and price (if they are contained inside that element...)  so product.find_element(...

Comment: I don't see any benefit to using the page source.  Your locators (xpath/css) are adept at dealing with the DOM to get what you need.